# Exporting mesh as CSV file

Tags: python, mesh, scripting, csv

I have been using this script to export my mesh to a CSV file. The problem is that every time I select a new object, the file is overwritten, so ideally when selecting a new object I need it to write a new CSV file, perhaps like this.  "mesh_001.csv", "mesh_002.csv" etc. Please could someone assist.

```
import bpy

outputFile = 'C:/My_Objects/mesh.csv'

verts = [ bpy.context.object.matrix_world @ v.co for v in bpy.context.object.data.vertices ]

csvLines = [ ";".join([ str(v) for v in co ]) + "\n" for co in verts ]

f = open( outputFile, 'w' )
f.writelines( csvLines )
f.close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Use the name of the object as the file name

```
import bpy
import os

name = bpy.context.object.name
outputFile  = bpy.path.abspath("//csv_export\\" + name + ".csv")

print(outputFile)
```

If I save my file in `D:\` and my object is named `Cube`, the `outputFile` will be `D:\csv_export\Cube.csv`.

## Increase a suffix number for each export

```
import bpy
import os

index = 0
while True:
    path = "//csv_export\\mesh" + str(index).zfill(4) + ".csv"
    outputFile = bpy.path.abspath(path)
    if not os.path.exists(outputFile):
        break
    index += 1

print(outputFile)
```

In this script, we initially construct a path to a file with the suffix `0 => mesh0000.csv`. While a file already exists at that location, we increase the counter.

Comment: It doesn't seem to create the new directory D:/csv_export and if I create it myself nothing is written into it when I run the script.  My .blend file is saved in the same D:/ directory. Maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: What code did you run? Was is [this](https://paste.ofcode.org/MnhCpt5LHRAtFVKxEzPP8H)?

Comment: Using the name of the object as file name.

Comment: Do you comprehend the script you posted?

Comment: I am not an expert at python, sorry. I sort of understand a few things. I am learning as I go.

Comment: The code snippets of my answer simply set the `ouputFile` variable. You still have to use the code in your Q which saves the file. I have combined them in the link given in my first comment.

Comment: In the example above, is it possible to create the directory folder D:/csv_export/ first,  before the csv file is written into it?

Comment: https://thispointer.com/how-to-create-a-directory-in-python/